# Behavior of SQLRowCount changes after a couple of rows are changed

Tags: windows, oracle, odbc, dsn

I've got a customer ODBC application that sanity-checks the rows affected after most operations.  All of a sudden, those checks are failing.  In this case, after an Insert the rows affected is expected to be 1.  After reviewing logs, that value is coming back unknown (-1).

Does anyone have any idea why the behavior would **change**?

Additional information:

- Application is running on a Windows server
- The database is Oracle.
- The driver is the Microsoft Oracle Driver
- The customer states that no upgrades to the database or drivers has happened recently.
- The customer claims the problem started after the changed/deleted a couple of rows in the table.

Additional details:

**The driver is the "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle", version is 2.576.3959.00, file name is MSORCL32.dll, date is 2/17/2007.  The Oracle database level is 10.2.**

Any ideas?

Here is the ODBC log I had them capture:

> ```
> dpxag35         a5c-cac   ENTER SQLExecDirect 
>       HSTMT               015A2270
>       UCHAR *             0x00177D9C [     364] "begin \  a <single simple insert statement here>; \ aend;"
>       SDWORD                   364
>
> dpxag35         a5c-cac   EXIT  SQLExecDirect  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
>       HSTMT               015A2270
>       UCHAR *             0x00177D9C [     364] "begin \  a <single simple insert statement here>; \ aend;"
>       SDWORD                   364
>
> dpxag35         a5c-cac   ENTER SQLNumResultCols 
>       HSTMT               015A2270
>       SWORD *             0x0012F9B0
>
> dpxag35         a5c-cac   EXIT  SQLNumResultCols  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
>       HSTMT               015A2270
>       SWORD *             0x0012F9B0 (0)
>
> dpxag35         a5c-cac   ENTER SQLRowCount 
>       HSTMT               015A2270
>       SQLLEN *            0x00163B88
>
> dpxag35         a5c-cac   EXIT  SQLRowCount  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
>       HSTMT               015A2270
>       SQLLEN *            0x00163B88 (-1)
>
> dpxag35         a5c-cac   ENTER SQLFreeStmt 
>       HSTMT               015A2270
>       UWORD                        0 <SQL_CLOSE>
>
> dpxag35         a5c-cac   EXIT  SQLFreeStmt  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
>       HSTMT               015A2270
>       UWORD                        0 <SQL_CLOSE>
> ```

---

For reference, this is from the ODBC docos on the MSDN:

> ***RowCountPtr*** [Output] Points to a buffer in which to return a row
>   count. For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, for the SQL_ADD,
>   SQL_UPDATE_BY_BOOKMARK, and SQL_DELETE_BY_BOOKMARK operations in
>   SQLBulkOperations, and for the SQL_UPDATE or SQL_DELETE operations in
>   SQLSetPos, the value returned in *RowCountPtr is either the number of
>   rows affected by the request or –1 if the number of affected rows is
>   not available. When SQLExecute, SQLExecDirect, SQLBulkOperations,
>   SQLSetPos, or SQLMoreResults is called, the SQL_DIAG_ROW_COUNT field
>   of the diagnostic data structure is set to the row count, and the row
>   count is cached in an implementation-dependent way. SQLRowCount
>   returns the cached row count value. The cached row count value is
>   valid until the statement handle is set back to the prepared or
>   allocated state, the statement is reexecuted, or SQLCloseCursor is
>   called. Note that if a function has been called since the
>   SQL_DIAG_ROW_COUNT field was set, the value returned by SQLRowCount
>   might be different from the value in the SQL_DIAG_ROW_COUNT field
>   because the SQL_DIAG_ROW_COUNT field is reset to 0 by any function
>   call. For other statements and functions, the driver may define the
>   value returned in *RowCountPtr. For example, some data sources may be
>   able to return the number of rows returned by a SELECT statement or a
>   catalog function before fetching the rows.  Note Many data sources
>   cannot return the number of rows in a result set before fetching them;
>   for maximum interoperability, applications should not rely on this
>   behavior.

And at the very end of the doco page, we get this:

> If the last SQL statement executed on the statement handle was not an
>   UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statement or if the Operation argument in
>   the previous call to SQLBulkOperations was not SQL_ADD,
>   SQL_UPDATE_BY_BOOKMARK, or SQL_DELETE_BY_BOOKMARK, or if the Operation
>   argument in the previous call to SQLSetPos was not SQL_UPDATE or
>   SQL_DELETE, the value of *RowCountPtr is driver-defined. For more
>   information, see Determining the Number of Affected Rows.

I guess it is plauable that because it was wrapped in a batch, it is yielding unknown.

But I cannot get past that this app has been running for **two years** and never had this problem.  The customer states they changed / deleted some table data and then the app failed.  I find it unlikely, experience tells me they did something else and aren't saying what.

Comment: Is it possible that insertion operations are not committed? This behavior may be affected by autocommit setting of ODBC driver. This feature exists for native ODBC driver which comes with Oracle, but I not sure about MS version. This settings corresponds to `SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT` parameter (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms713605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I will check what the settings are just in case, though supposedly nothing changed (the system has been running for 2 years).  The PL/SQL getting executed was wrapped in a begin/end to create a batch, wouldn't that be enough either way?  Also, the update is getting written to the database, so it is at least getting committed eventually.

Comment: Ah, read the AUTOCOMMIT docos more closely, the sql batch doesn't matter if autocommit is set to off.  Definitely worth checking.

Comment: I must read more about ODBC trace because don't figure out that all happens inside single session. Sorry.

Comment: Did you check ODBC driver version? And what version of Oracle DBMS installed? Is it possible that customer faced the issue like described here http://forums.datadirect.com/ddforums/thread.jspa?threadID=4312 ?

Comment: As described in MSDN documentation ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ) behavior  of SQLRowCount after execution of batch operation (I suppose it's to be a batch, because it enclosed in `begin` ... `end;` ) is driver-defined, it's one more reason to check ODBC driver version.

Comment: I'm attempting to get remote access to the machine so I can check the driver version information.  I can't image they would have changed it, but maybe some type of auto update since it is a MS driver?

Comment: Added the driver info to the question.

Comment: If you can provide some information about client application (e.g. programming language, is it native code or any managed language and so on) and version of OS running on client with adding appropriate tags to the question, then may be you  find answer faster by capture the attention of more people. For now I can't find reasonable answer, sorry.

Comment: ODBC is programming-language neutral.  The PC OS was, to my surprise,  Windows Server 2003.  @ThinkJet, post your comment "As described in MSDN documentation..." as an answer and I will award to you.  I tested the insert without the batch and I did get 1 row affect back.  So it seems to be batch-releated.

Comment: Nice to hear about your progress in solving the problem. Answer added as you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), behavior of `SQLRowCount` after execution of batch operation (I suppose it's to be a batch, because it enclosed in begin ... end; ) is driver-defined, it's a good reason to check ODBC driver version.

Comment: At the end of the day, "driver-defined" is not reliable enough to count on the row count after a batch.  Time to go back through and do a quick code review.